# Error when calling a plpgsql function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, quoting

Following is my `function` created in `PostgreSQL 9.2`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function fn_exp_settl_cr
(branchid int
 ,vrid int
 ,ddate date
 ,acid int
) 
returns 
TABLE ( trno character varying(15), trdate timestamp without time zone, netamt money, duedate 
        timestamp without time zone,tranid integer, acyrid integer, custrefno  
        charactervarying(26), orderdate timestamp without time zone) as $$
declare 
sql text;
begin
execute 'select string_agg(s.qry,'' UNION ALL '')  from (select ''SELECT 
         TrNo,TrDate,NetAmt,DueDate,TranId,AcYrId,custrefno,orderdate FROM '||t.relname||' WHERE 
         AdjInBill = false And  ExpSettled = false And (BranchID = 1) AND (VrId = 29) and   
         DueDate <= ''2014-07-24'' and AcId=76 '' qry from (select relname from 
         pg_stat_user_tables where relname ilike ''gtab09%'') t )s ' into sql;
execute sql;
end;
$$ language plpgsql
```

It creates successfully but when calling this function, i.e.:

```
select * from fn_exp_settl_cr(1,2,'2014-07-24',4)
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "t" LINE 1:
>   ...DueDate,TranId,AcYrId,custrefno,orderdate FROM '||t.relname|...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function fn_exp_settl_cr(_branchid int, _vrid int
                                         , _ddate date, _acid int)
  RETURNS TABLE (
   trno character varying(15)
 , trdate timestamp
 , netamt money
 , duedate timestamp
 , tranid integer
 , acyrid integer
 , custrefno  character varying(26)
 , orderdate timestamp
) AS
$func$
BEGIN

RETURN QUERY EXECUTE (
   SELECT string_agg
            (format
               ($$SELECT TrNo,TrDate,NetAmt,DueDate,TranId,AcYrId
                        ,custrefno,orderdate
                  FROM   %I
                  WHERE  AdjInBill = false
                  AND    ExpSettled = false
                  AND    BranchID = $1
                  AND    VrId = $2
                  AND    DueDate <= $3
                  AND    AcId = $4
                $$
               ,t.relname
               )
            ,' UNION ALL '
            )
   FROM   pg_class t
   WHERE  t.relkind = 'r' -- ordinary table
   AND    t.relname ILIKE 'gtab09%'
   )
USING _branchid, _vrid, _ddate, _acid;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

#### Major points

- Your format is hardly readable, which is probably the main reason you can't find the problem.
- Typo in `charactervarying(26)`. Fix: `character varying(26)`. I would just use `varchar` or `text`, though.
- You got confused with multiple layers of **quoting**. The fix is to use dollar-quoting and `format()` to build your string. Also, one or two layers can just be simplified away.
- You are not actually using your input parameters. Probably because you got stuck and are testing with literal values. While being at it, I built those in, too, with a `USING` clause.
- I suggest not to use the same identifiers as parameter names. Those are visible in the function body everywhere and easily lead to naming conflicts. Prepended with '_'.
- You didn't actually return anything. Use `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE` instead of just `EXECUTE` for that end.

And why retrieve table names from the [statistics view `pg_stat_user_tables`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/monitoring-stats.html)? It's cheaper and more reliable to get it from the information schema or the catalog table `pg_class`. Changed that, too.