# How to append strings in PL/pgSQL?

Tags: amazon-redshift, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have a procedure that queries schema and table. I want this to not overwrite the variable instead append, because the result I want to create view.

```
DECLARE    
    rec record;
    sqlPlaceholder text;
BEGIN
 
 FOR rec IN SELECT table_schema, table_name
            FROM information_schema.tables                
 LOOP
     sqlPlaceholder := sqlPlaceholder || 'SELECT ogc_fid, wkb_geometry FROM ' || 
               rec.table_schema || '.' || rec.table_name || ' UNION ';
 END LOOP;
  
strSQL := 'SELECT  * FROM (' || sqlPlaceholder || ')';

RAISE INFO 'sample output %' , strSQL;
```

The variable `sqlPlaceholder` only holds the last assignment from the loop. as it's overwritten by each loop.

I need to figure out how add them all in loop.

```
call create_view()

Value of string inside loop SELECT *  FROM public._data_202101 UNION 
Value of string inside loop SELECT *  FROM public._data_202102 UNION 
Value of string inside loop SELECT *  FROM public._data_202103 UNION 
Value of string inside loop SELECT *  FROM public._data_202104 UNION 
Value of string inside loop SELECT *  FROM public._data_202105 UNION 
Value of string inside loop SELECT *  FROM public._data_202106 UNION 
Value of string inside loop SELECT *  FROM public._data_202107 UNION 
Value of string inside loop SELECT *  FROM public._data_202108 UNION 
Value of string inside loop SELECT *  FROM public._data_202109 UNION 
Value of string inside loop SELECT *  FROM public._data_202110 UNION 
Value of string inside loop SELECT *  FROM public._data_202111 UNION 
Value of string inside loop SELECT *  FROM public._data_202112 UNION 
Value of string outside ==> create table public._data_all as (SELECT *  FROM public._data_202112 union)
```

Comment: Are you sure? You could add a debug line (`RAISE INFO`) in the loop to see the value of `sqlPlaceholder` during each loop execution.

Comment: Note: if the loop executes N times you'll need N-1 `' UNION '` s.

Comment: yes, I did added inside the loop also, here is the output of that, added in answer

Answer (score 3):

The core problem in your PL/pgSQL code is that `sqlPlaceholder` starts out as NULL. [Read the manual here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html)

`NULL || anything` is always `NULL`. Initialize the variable with an empty string (`''`) instead to fix that:

```
DECLARE    
    sqlPlaceholder text := '';
...
```

There's more, but don't bother. Here is a superior set-based solution:

```sql
SELECT string_agg(format('SELECT ogc_fid, wkb_geometry FROM %I.%I', table_schema, table_name), E'\nUNION ')
FROM   information_schema.tables;
```

Redshift is pretty limited, I don't think it has `format()`. So:

```sql
SELECT string_agg('SELECT ogc_fid, wkb_geometry FROM ' || quote_ident(table_schema) || '.' || quote_ident(table_name), '\nUNION ')
FROM   information_schema.tables;
```

Produces something like:

```sql
SELECT ogc_fid, wkb_geometry FROM public.tbl1
UNION SELECT ogc_fid, wkb_geometry FROM public.tbl2
UNION SELECT ogc_fid, wkb_geometry FROM public.tbl3
...
```

You want to quote identifiers properly to defend against SQL injection in any case! See:

- [INSERT with dynamic table name in trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914325/insert-with-dynamic-table-name-in-trigger-function/7915100#7915100)
- [quote_ident() does not add quotes to column name "first"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66662580/quote-ident-does-not-add-quotes-to-column-name-first/66664718#66664718)

Also, you probably want some filter and `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.

Related:

- [Loop through like tables in a schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21144531/loop-through-like-tables-in-a-schema/21145111#21145111)
- [Error when calling a plpgsql function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26527525/error-when-calling-a-plpgsql-function/26530045#26530045)

Comment: i'm getting this error 

Schema Error: error: unterminated quoted string at or near "E'\nUNION ) FROM information_schema.tables;"

Comment: The missing single quote is already fixed.

Comment: on the new one I get some other issue, maybe it's not supported 

[42883] ERROR: function format("unknown", information_schema.sql_identifier, information_schema.sql_identifier) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: I already addressed that, too, by now.

Comment: looks like e is not supported in redshift either.
[42704] ERROR: type "e" does not exist

Comment: Yeah, Redshift is stuck in the past where Postgres has long since evolved. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320729/939860

Comment: @hi4ppl: this is precisely the reason you shouldn't tag Redshift questions with Postgres.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the only reason I tagged was that the same procedure have same result both in redshift and PostgreSQL so I needed that to work in both, I appreciate the insight and help, but my question was why the variable overwritten on each loop and how to append in variable.

Comment: @hi4ppl: I added an explanation for the original question, too. (In case you missed it.)

Comment: So is this answered properly?